# How to control scope in node callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Playing around i found that the *this* object across callbacks on the same object stays the same. Is it wise to use this for scope control as follows.

```
process.stdin.once('data', (chunk) => {
    this.count = 0;
})

process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
    this.count += chunk.length;
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
    console.log(`N of bytes ${this.count}`);
});
```

As I do not see this often, I'm wondering if anything is wrong with it or better methods of doing the same exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works yes. The reason is you have no exterior closure, and your listeners all use es6 arrow functions so `this` is never bound to the callbacks. They all reference the global `this`.

A cleaner way might be to wrap them in a closure and reference a scoped variable.

The IIFE example in @Jamiec's answer would serve your purposes. Just edit the es6 template literal to use ` instead of " as a wrapper as follows:

```
(function(){
    var count = 0;

    process.stdin.once('data', (chunk) => {
        count = 0;
    })

    process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
        count += chunk.length;
    });

    process.stdin.on('end', () => {
        console.log(`N of bytes ${count}`);
    });    
})()
```

Comment: Haha gotta love SO sometimes. Your answer basically says "Jamiec's answer is right" and you get the upvote. Anyway, +1 from me too!

Comment: Actually my answer was right before your answer was posted. I added your example, fixed it because it wouldn't of worked, and gave you credit. I also upvoted you...

Comment: My answer was upvoted before I referenced your example... Anyhow, have a great day!

Comment: @KyleRichardson (removed his comment, but I answer it anyway...) first of, your example don't scope "this" you are scoping "count".. and it would be possible to do in the same way as I edited your answer. Plus, my answer demanded way less code... it's also not a complete nock of of the correct answer already provided by Jamiec. gl hf...

Comment: I removed my comment because it was irrelevant. My answer actually explains what is happening, not just a code example. Your edit was also worthless in my opinion, which is why I declined it. Accept it and move on.

Comment: "Accept it and move on." ??? what? I answered to your comment... And you stated in your former comment that you declined the edit because you thought it would defeat the purpose of the example, which is incorrect, why I responded to correct you.. now you change you mind to something else.... ? yhea m8, I move on.. gl m8...

Comment: What is your issue? You upvoted my answer, editted, got declined, removed upvoted, and start downvoting? Thanks for your thoughts :)

Answer (score 3):

functions have their own scope, you could use that:

```
function doSomething(){
    var count = 0;

    process.stdin.once('data', (chunk) => {
        count = 0;
    })

    process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
        count += chunk.length;
    });

    process.stdin.on('end', () => {
        console.log(`N of bytes ${count}`);
    });

}
```

If there's no need to call this function from elsewhere, and you just want it to execute you could make it an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
(function(){
    var count = 0;

    process.stdin.once('data', (chunk) => {
        count = 0;
    })

    process.stdin.on('data', (chunk) => {
        count += chunk.length;
    });

    process.stdin.on('end', () => {
        console.log(`N of bytes ${count}`);
    });

})()
```

Note: Edited to correct the wrong char used for templated strings (` not ")